# Named pipe which is waiting to connect for a few weeks

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pipe, named-pipes

I have a strange problem with named pipes, so here is the description:

I use named pipes in order to transfer cache between new and old instances of an application.

it happens like this:

**1)** When the application starts, it tries to connect and receive cache from an old instance of the application.

**2)** When the application started, it's ready to provide cache to the next new application.

**3)** I have 2 pipes, let's call them, `pipe1` and `pipe2`

**3.1)** the first app uses `pipe1` to provide cache and `pipe2` to receive cache

**3.2)** the second app uses vice verse, `pipe2` to provide cache and `pipe1` to receive cache

**4)** after new app started, the old one will be destroyed

**5)** instances of the application work on the same machine

in general, it works fine. (if I update my app once a day or once in two, three days)

but I haven't done it (updates) for a few weeks and I have encountered to the problem: the application works for a couple of weeks without updating. it means that the first app kept pipe1 opened for a couple of weeks, and when I started updating, the new instance of the app (at least as I can judge according to my logs) connected to the old instance to the pipe1 and just froze! nothing was happening, it wasn't able to start in other words.

## Questions:

**1)** for how long a pipe can be opened? for example, if I use this:

`pipe.BeginWaitForConnection(myCallBack, pipe);`

if I want to connect in a few weeks to the pipe, is it still be opened and ready to work?

**2)** or what might have gone wrong here?

*just want to remind: it worked fine before this 'long' period of time between updates.

thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions!

**update 1**: Actually I have 3 couples of named pipes

(A1 A2), (B1 B2), (C1 C2) in that example A1 is equal to `pipe1` and A2 is equal to `pipe2`. and the algorithm is the same for each couple. (one couple for transferring cache, another one for transferring user's sessions, etc)

the first pair (A1 A2) got the exception `System.IO.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired`

and only the second pair froze...